# Diffrence between an static_cast to a number and pointer content

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference, static-cast

I'm wondering why this work

```
int i = 1;
int& ri = i;
int* pi = &i;

// does work
ri = static_cast<int&>(*pi);
// does not work cause I try to assign an reference to an rvalue
ri = static_cast<int&>(1);
```

So why does the

```
ri = static_cast<int&>(*pi);
```

work then ? I am accessing the pointer content which should be equal to one as well. Thanks a lot.

Cheers

Sebastian

Comment: Because you can't take a reference to a literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pi`, the pointer variable, is a rvalue in itself. The moment you add a `*` in front of it, the result is a lvalue. lvalue references are completely valid, which is why `ri = static_cast<int&>(*pi);` works. The exception to this rule is const lvalue references, which can be assigned rvalue references.

Checkout the article [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c) to understand the difference between lvalue and rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

1 is a constant, and does not have a memory address, so you can't use it as a reference. If you could do this, what would this code do?

```
ri = static_cast<int&>(1);
ri++;
```

Comment: Yeah I get this point :-) 
I'm not wondering why the last line doesn't work, I'm wondering why the first static_cast with static_cast<int&>(*pi) does work.

Comment: *pi is i so *pi does have an address, the address of i

Comment: and the compiler automatically dereferences the adress of an variable  normally ?

Tought that pi holds the address, where the var i is saved and *pi directly reads the memory. So I guess you can't say that *pi does have the adress of of i

Comment: You can't say that *pi does have the address of i : 

&pi - Address where the pointer on his own is saved
pi holds the address where the variable i is saved  
*pi access the address to which it points to

Comment: You're right...in fact I think the compiler is smart enough to see that *pi is the value of a pointer so he knows that ri will point on the address contained in pi.

Comment: Yes it's normal because pi is a pointer. You need to pass an int, for example i or *pi. When you pass *pi, the compiler will translate it to «ri will point to the same address than pi».